# Xephyr: mouse does not move smoothly

Tags: debian, xorg, mouse, x-server, xephyr

I am using `xserver-xephyr` in Debian Wheezy. My mouse inside the `Xephyr` window does not move smoothly. It looks as if the refresh rate was very low. When I move my mouse across the screen, it maybe refreshes 3 times. This looks more like the cursor was jumping, rather than moving smoothly.

Is it there some configuration I can change to make the mouse cursor move as smooth as normally ?

Comment: Hi again, did you solve your [previous problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186273/emulate-key-combination-with-xdotool)?

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk - no, but I got better at pressing the key combination. I have to hold `control_L` with my left hand and press `shift_L` with my right hand. Then the grab/ungrab works reliably. I have no idea why that is so.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration Try few commands from above link within a session. If it works, then we can fine tune the Xephyr configuration for the same reason

Comment: @SHW - that article describes how to change acceleration. But my problem seems to be different - mouse does not move smoothly. Besides, how can I edit `xorg.conf` only for `Xephyr` ? I don't want to change settings for normal `xorg`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the -host-cursor option.

Edit: per the Xephyr man page, this option reuses the host X session's cursor. Theoretically this is not supposed to produce a significant performance improvement. In practice, I've found that Xephyr's cursor is very slow on lower-spec machines, and this option handily fixes that issue every time.

It would be invoked by e.g.

```
Xephyr -host-cursor -screen 800x600 :1
```

Comment: with `-host-cursor`, the cursor indeed moves perfectly smoothly. But a new problem is, the cursor shows as arrow all the time (i.e. does not change when I hover over a link, for instance).

Comment: I'm guessing that can't be helped; probably a limitation of how X11 works.